# how to eliminate empty arrays from an array of arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

i have an array of arrays. from this i want to eliminate the empty arrays.

iam using `reject!(&:empty?)` method. but it is giving me unexpected results.

```
2.2.2 :306 >   array = ["yes","yes","yes"]
 => ["yes", "yes", "yes"] 
2.2.2 :307 > array.split("no")
 => [["yes", "yes", "yes"]] 
2.2.2 :308 > array.split("no").reject!(&:empty?)
 => nil 
2.2.2 :309 > array_with_no = ["yes","yes","yes","no"]
 => ["yes", "yes", "yes", "no"] 
2.2.2 :310 > array_with_no.split("no")
 => [["yes", "yes", "yes"], []] 
2.2.2 :311 > array.split("no").reject!(&:empty?)
 => nil 
2.2.2 :312 > array_with_no.split("no").reject!(&:empty?)
 => [["yes", "yes", "yes"]] 
2.2.2 :313 >
```

i want the result where when there is no empty array to eliminate, then it should return the same array instead of returning `nil`

Comment: you need multidimensional array always ?, or result may be in single dimensional array  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need result in single dimension then you can use simply:

```
[["yes", "yes", "yes"], []].flatten.compact
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delete_if`:

```
array = [["yes","yes","yes"], [], []]
array.delete_if{|x| x.empty?}
```

it will return  `[["yes","yes","yes"]`

Or if you want to combine array of arrays you may use `flatten`:

```
array = ["yes","yes","yes"], [], []].flatten
```

it will return `["yes","yes","yes"]`

Answer (score 0):

You want `reject` instead of `reject!` (the !-version modifies the array in-place and returns `true` or `nil` depending on if changes to the array were made or not)

[Documentation on what the methods do](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21)

Answer (score 0):

Use select.

```
array.split("no").select(&:present?)


=> [["yes", "yes", "yes"]]
```

Alternatively you can remove the bang from your reject and that will also give you what you want.

```
array.split("no").reject(&:empty?)

=> [["yes", "yes", "yes"]]
```

The ! on reject! will destructively modify the array in place and will return nil if no changes were made.